# Opencart localhost site redirects to live site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost, opencart

I am using Opencart 1.5.6.1, and just migrated my live site to localhost. I made a database with the same name and the same username, imported the exact database from the live site, copied all the files from the live site to localhost, changed links in config.php file in both admin and frontend, removed .htaccess altogether.

I get the admin page for
`localhost/mysitename/admin`
But
`localhost/mysitename`
is being redirected to the live site at
`mysite.com`

I searched online and here on SO - but no solution worked. Someone also suggested to change Apache's `httpd-vhosts.conf` - but that didn't help either. I am attaching my `config.php` file, and I have no `.htaccess` file. I don't know, where else to check, what to change.

```
// HTTP define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/sistawigtest/');
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://localhost/sistawigtest/');
// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistawigtest/system/logs/');
```

If you need to see anything else, I can add that too. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I tried loading static files like sale_email.html or image file on the root directory - these are not being redirected.

Comment: Did you try the local site before removing the `.htaccess`? You may just need to clear your browser cache completely if you tried it before removing the `.htaccess` file and that auto redirected to the site

Comment: I tried it before removing .htaccess and I cleared cache, tried different browser to see but it still redirects.

Comment: What happens if you go to http://localhost/sistawigtest/?route=account/login ? Does it redirect or stay local?

Comment: Are you using opencart multi-store feature? Is 'mysite.com' your default store?

Comment: Jay, It gets redirected with that link also. Sankar, I am using Default store. I dont have multi-store. mysite.com is live site and its default store on opencart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main culprit was a script on header.tpl file

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\mytestsite\catalog\view\theme\lexus_megashop\template\common
```

I found this script and just removed it and redirection stopped.

```
 <script async type="text/javascript" >
    var strUrl = location.href;
    if(strUrl.indexOf("www") == -1){
        location.href = "http://www.testsite.com";
    }
</script>
```